# In Delphi, what do I do about "no GetEnumerator present" error when using a for loop over Excel Interop Worksheets collection?

Tags: delphi, excel, interop, for-in-loop

I'm trying to write a Delphi program that will loop through each worksheet in an Excel file and format some cells. I'm receiving an error while trying to use the for-in loop over the Workbook.Worksheets collection, though. The error is specifically:

> [DCC Error] Office.pas(36): E2431
>   for-in statement cannot operate on
>   collection type 'Sheets' because
>   'Sheets' does not contain a member for
>   'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible

The line of code this occurs for is:

```
for Worksheet in Workbook.Worksheets do
```

The definition of Worksheet and Workbook is as follows:

```
var ExcelApp: ExcelApplication;
var Workbook: ExcelWorkbook;
var Worksheet: ExcelWorksheet;
```

I'm porting this code to Delphi from C#, in which it works. Does anyone know why I'd be getting this GetEnumerator error? I'm using the Office 2007 Excel Interop file and Embarcadero® Delphi® 2010 Version 14.0.3593.25826.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how C# handles enumerable collections, but for Delphi, it looks for a method on the collection called GetEnumerator, which returns an enumerator.  The enumerator must be a data structure that contains at least the following two members:

```
public
  function MoveNext: boolean;
  property Current: <some type> read <some read method>;
end;
```

If Delphi says 'Sheets' does not contain a member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible, then that means exactly what it says.  Either there's no GetEnumerator on Sheets, or it's not a public method.  What does the definition of Sheets look like?

Comment: The definition of Sheets can be found here, on MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets_methods(office.11).aspx That is a link to the methods available within Sheets. So, the GetEnumerator method does exist and is public.

Comment: OK, looks like it exists, but the compiler can't find it.  If this is coming from another language, you're accessing it through a translated header or interface definition somewhere.  Check and make sure that it's got GetEnumerator declared.

Comment: Ok. Yea, I'm importing a unit using the Excel Type Library. It doesn't look like there's any trace of GetEnumerator in the unit that it's creating. Looks like I might have to use the For loop as saalon stated below.

Comment: @Ryan: Can you just edit the definition from the Excel Type Library and add the GetEnumerator declaration?

Answer (score 1):

C# handles enumerators similar to Delphi. There is an IEnumerable interface that has two methods: MoveNext, and Reset; and also one property called Current.

For ExcelWorkBook.Sheets property, you should take note that although MSDN documentation says it has a GetEnumerator method, this class's definition in ExcelXP unit provided by Delphi does not provide such a method. 
So maybe you have to import a newer version of its type library into Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Based on comments, the GetEnumerator method exists for the object, so this solution is likely incorrect.**

It's been a while since I've used Delphi, but my guess based on the error is that the ExcelWorksheet collection is not enumerated, which would mean doing a for/each style loop would not work and you'd need to use a C-like for loop:

```
 For  i := 1 to Length(Workbook.Worksheets) do
  Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets[i];
end;
```

Comment: According to MSDN, it does have a GetEnumerator method, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.getenumerator(office.11).aspx

Perhaps I'm not properly instanciating the objects? I'm new to Delphi. Here's what I've got in my implementation portion.

http://pastebin.com/QaxUXuZ2

Comment: I think Mason's comment above might be the right direction to go. I remember that when importing COM assemblies in Delphi it creates a big interface definition. GetEnumerator might not be declared there.

(By the way, I totally pity you having to move anything from C# to Delphi).